# Multiple Lines in Json file

Tags: json, string

I am storing some query in json file. the query is little bit lengthy. I want to store these query in multiple lines to show query clearly. In C# when we have like this query we put in the front of query @ .. Is there any special key to put in the front of json string?
below is image what I mean by this.  [image: image of query in json]

Comment: Please post actual text instead of images of text.

Comment: I don't want to handle with javascript. I want to handle with C#. but first it become a valid Json format.

Comment: I post image because the color of the multiple line will not be the different color. and reader will not get the point where the error

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this; newlines are not allowed in JSON strings [[1]](http://json.org).

Comment: ok.. Thanks.. then I will store in one line.